# Copying and pasting padding issue in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

I am still using Windows XP. My work requires quite a lot of copying and pasting of usernames and passwords. Some times it happens that when I copy some content and paste it somewhere, I get padding spaces in the end or sometimes before. It is really typical to write each password down by keyboard if you can copy and paste it. Does anyone of you had this problem? Please let me know what should I do.

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT:

I get usernames and passwords in email and I select the text by a mouse and copy them using CTRL+C and paste them using CTRL+V

Comment: why do you get padding? you did not describe the layout of the data, or even the program you are copying from.  Do you apply the Double Left Mouse Click Select for text? that would select the "word" without the spaces. tripple click selects the line and usually avoids the spaces.  Do these methods work in the progam your grabbing the data from?  Theses methods are very clutzy at first, but after a hundred or so , it should flow like picking them up with your hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happens here to, when there are actual spaces at the end of the word(s), Actual spaces instead of periods commas EOLs.  I never noticed it before because most of my copy paste the space is usefull.

When C&P the Form Data on a "web box", there are No spaces there before or after.  EX: C&P my e-mail I just typed to a form that wants the e-mail twice, to insure I typed correctally. Works correct everytime.  I never C&P a "secure" password, and the lesser passwords are fast to type, so they dont matter.  That just leave pulling a Password out of a e-mail sent for log-in, I do not recall ever having a problem with that.  They control that e-mail and they usually EOL after it in the e-mail.

I donno, but some ideas, Increase the font size, on either the e-mail program or the DPI on the OS, that would be one way to speed it up a bit because you would have more pixels of leeway.  If you are in control of the formatting of the e-mail, get EOLs or hex 00s in there right after the words??
If the e-mails are RTF formatted, force the e-mail program to read them as "text only" so any larger font settings are used everytime.

Get a MUCH better T-Beam (text select) cursor. I had to make my own , and customise the exact center point of the cursor and prime it for text selection (as it should have been originally)

want to try it? http://www.mediafire.com/?1j6bx05ppejiocx (teeney cursor file)

comes with instructions too :-)  Start the text beam pointer center on the first few pixels of the first letter, end your sweeping text selection with the text beam pointer center just past the center of the last letter. that is how it was designed.

Get a Trackball like the huge one they use in the arcades , when you cant afford or assemble that, get a big Cue ball sized trackball, it is much more control than a mouse once you get used to it.